# Translating plugin inside the theme

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes, translation

I've developped a WordPress Business theme and I use it to sell websites to local businesses. Everything works like a charm.

But. One thing doesn't.

I've included the Redux plugin into my theme. So it's in themedirectory/redux. I know it's considered bad practice but it's not meant for the WP theme repository, and it gives me full control over my theme. The redux-plugin inside my theme has a languages folder and the main redux-framework.pot file contains all my custom strings. But when I translate the .pot file I don't know where to save the translated file, and how I should call it.

So this is what I've tried:
taking the main redux-framework.pot (located in themedirectory/redux/languages) file, translate it to dutch and saved it as the following:

*nl_NL.po/mo* in themedirectory/redux/languages

*redux-framework-nl_NL.po/mo* in themedirectory/redux/languages

*redux-nl_NL.po/mo* in themedirectory/redux/languages

But none of them seem to work. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: This is not a Generic PHP/JS/SQL/HTML/CSS, why is it on hold

Comment: Wut. How is this off-topic?